# Dealing with npm packages minor breaking changes

Tags: npm, npm-install

While using npm I've not once encountered a problem when some package somewhere deep in the dependency tree receives minor or even patch update, but actually introduces a breaking change. Finding the culprit package is not always easy. And the problem most of the time hits CI the hardest as it often performs clean *npm install*. So all that remains is waiting a day or two till package authors notice and fix the error.

Using exact versions in package.json doesn't help either as referenced packages have dependencies of their own and they are not always specified with exact versions.

Such breaking changes are a fact of life I suppose, as no one is immune to mistakes, and shear number of packages directly and indirectly used in any bigger than trivial project is huge.

So, how to prevent such inevitable breaking changes from disrupting development process?

The only thing I've been able to imagine is a hypothetical feature of npm that would only allow installing packages no younger than `now().addDays(-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

A `package-lock.json` (npm5) or a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` (npm 2-4) if created and committed to source control will lock in all of your dependencies and their dependencies so that the exact same versions will be installed.  `package-lock.json` is now generated automatically, and `npm-shrinkwrap.json` can be created with `npm shrinkwrap` command.  Once these files are created, they will be automatically updated on subsequent `npm install --save ...` commands.